# $.mobile.loading animation during $.mobile.changePage

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I kind of struggle with this issue for a while. My intention is to show the spinning wheel to the user while $.mobile.changePage method is redirecting him to another page. However, none of the solutions I found work for me. It must be some issue with changePage method killing the loading animation becasue when i put away the changePage method then spinning wheel shows up. Thanks for your help.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $( document ).bind( 'mobileinit', function(){
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "loading";
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = false;
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
              $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
        });
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onBodyLoad();">
    <!-- LOGIN PAGE -->
    <div data-role="page" id="login_page">
      <div data-role="content" id="login_content">
        <div id="buttons">
          <button value="Login" id="login">Login</button>
          <button value="Logout" id="logout">Logout</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- TIMELINE PAGE -->
    <div data-role="page" id="timeline_page">
      <div data-role="header" id="timeline_head" data-nobackbtn="true">
        <h1>BlueBirdGap</h1>
        <h2>Timeline</h2>
        <a id="timeline_button_back" data-icon="arrow-l" class="ui-btn-left" 
        href="javascript:return true;" data-role="button" data-inline="true">Zpět</a>
        <div data-role="controlgroup" class="ui-btn-right">
          <a id="logout_button" data-icon="delete" data-role="button">Logout</a>
          <a id="new_tweet_button" data-icon="plus" data-role="button" data-theme="b">Tweet</a>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" id="timeline_content">
        <div id="new_tweet_area">
          <textarea id="tweet_text"></textarea>
          <button data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b" class="ui-btn-right" onclick="Twitter.post()">Post</button>
        </div>
        <div id="home_timeline"></div>
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer" id="timeline_footer"></div>
    </div>



   <script>
    function onBodyLoad() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        }

    function onDeviceReady() {
            cb = window.plugins.childBrowser;
            $('html').addClass( "ui-loading" );

            if(localStorage.getItem(twitterKey)){
                showLogin(1);
                $.mobile.loading('show');
                Twitter.timeline();
                $.mobile.changePage('#timeline_page', {transition: "slide"});
                $.mobile.loading('hide');
             }
    }
    </script>
```

I should add that I'm working on an Android application using PhoneGap framework and JQM 1.3.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();` and `$.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();` instead of `$.mobile.loading();`.

However, in case they didn't work, use the below code.

to show the loading spinner.

```
$('div.ui-loader').show();
```

to hide it.

```
$('div.ui-loader').hide();
```

The loading spinner is hidden in a div before the `</body>` as follows. All you need is to either `show();` it or `hide();` it.

```
<div class="ui-loader ui-corner-all ui-body-a ui-loader-default" style="display: block;">
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-loading">
 </span>
 <h1>loading</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` is depreciated. You should not use it.

Comment: Mayu is correct. However the methods are still in there and defer any calls to the preferred method which is: $.mobile.loading which in turn invokes the 'loaderWidget'. This widget only exists AFTER the 'pagecontainerCreate' event has fired. (See JQM 1.3.1, lines:1115-1117)

More details: [jqmDoco](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/loader.html)